# vba output 2D an array to sheet issue

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I'm trying to output the following 2D array to a sheet in a Workbook. The code runs but the array is not visible on the sheet. Please help me find the error. Thanks

```
Dim R As Long, C As Long, vArr As Variant

vArr = Array(Array("N", "c.181C > a", "p.Q61K", "", "0.11"), _
              Array("C", "c.98C > a", "p.S33Y", "", "36%"), _
              Array("K", "c.2447A > T", "p.D816V", "", "8"), _
              Array("B", "c.1799T > T", "p.V600E", "", "0.08"), _
              Array("N", "c.181C > a", "p.Q61K", "", "0.11"), _
              Array("C", "c.98C > a", "p.S33Y", "", "36"), _
              Array("N", "c.181C > a", "p.Q61K", "", "0.11"), _
              Array("C", "c.98C > a", "p.S33Y", "", "36"))

  For R = LBound(vArr) To UBound(vArr)
    For C = LBound(vArr(LBound(vArr))) To UBound(vArr(UBound(vArr)))
      'MsgBox "vArr(" & R & ")(" & C & ") = " & vArr(R)(C)
    Next
  Next
LRow = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row

Sheets("Sheet2").Select
Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("C" & LRow + 1 & ":G" & LRow + 9).Value = vArr
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For one thing you were trying to paste something which had 8 rows into a range with 9 rows. But -- the more fundamental problem is that in VBA an array of arrays is different from a 2 - dimensional array. You should convert to a 2-d array before pasting:

```
Sub test()

    Dim R As Long, C As Long, vArr As Variant
    Dim vArr2 As Variant
    Dim LRow As Long

    vArr = Array(Array("N", "c.181C > a", "p.Q61K", "", "0.11"), _
                  Array("C", "c.98C > a", "p.S33Y", "", "36%"), _
                  Array("K", "c.2447A > T", "p.D816V", "", "8"), _
                  Array("B", "c.1799T > T", "p.V600E", "", "0.08"), _
                  Array("N", "c.181C > a", "p.Q61K", "", "0.11"), _
                  Array("C", "c.98C > a", "p.S33Y", "", "36"), _
                  Array("N", "c.181C > a", "p.Q61K", "", "0.11"), _
                  Array("C", "c.98C > a", "p.S33Y", "", "36"))

    ReDim vArr2(0 To 7, 0 To 4)
    For R = 0 To 7
        For C = 0 To 4
            vArr2(R, C) = vArr(R)(C)
        Next C
    Next R

    LRow = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    Sheets("Sheet2").Select
    Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("C" & LRow + 1 & ":G" & LRow + 8).Value = vArr2

End Sub
```

Comment: FYI, as long as there are less than 65536 items in the main array, you can just use: `Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("C" & lRow + 1 & ":G" & lRow + 8).Value = Application.Index(vArr, 0)`

Comment: Thank John, How do I convert what I have to a 2-D array?

Comment: Thanks Rory, it Worked!

Comment: @user3781528  My code showed how to do it. vArr2 is the 2-dimensional version of your vArr. You could also try pasting your original data row by row (or use Rory's slick approach).