# match values from sheet to array and return a corresponding value if a match is found

Tags: excel, vba

I need to lookup values from a sheet (the last 8 characters from column 1 & the content of column 6) in an array. If a match is found the corresponding value column 2 of the array needs to be populated into column 9 on the sheet. When I run my code there are no errors but nothing is returned into column 9.

Please help me fix the problem with my code. Thank you so much for your time.

```
Sub LookupValues()

Dim LastRow, i As Long
Dim GeneCheck As String
Dim vArr As Variant
Dim x

LastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

vArr = Array(Array("HD300_QCL861Q", "5"), _
Array("HD300_QCE746_E749del", "5"), _
Array("HD300_QCL858R", "5"), _
Array("HD300_QCT790M", "5"), _
Array("HD300_QCG719S", "5"), _
Array("HD200_QCV600E", "10.5"), _
Array("HD200_QCD816V", "10"), _
Array("HD200_QCE746_E749del", "2"), _
Array("HD200_QCL858R", "3"), _
Array("HD200_QCT790M", "1"), _
Array("HD200_QCG719S", "24.5"), _
Array("HD200_QCG13D", "15"), _
Array("HD200_QCG12D", "6"), _
Array("HD200_QCQ61K", "12.5"), _
Array("HD200_QCH1047R", "17.5"), _
Array("HD200_QCE545K", "9"))



For i = 2 To LastRow

GeneCheck = Right(Cells(i, 1).Value, 8) & Cells(i, 6).Value

'//Tell VBA to ignore an error and continue (ie if it can't find the value)
        On Error Resume Next

'//Assign the result of your calculation to a variable that VBA can query

x = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(GeneCheck, vArr, 2, False)

     '//if Vlookup finds the value, then paste it into the required column
        If Err = 0 Then
Cells(i, 9).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction(GeneCheck, vArr, 2, False)
        End If

        '//resets to normal error handling
        On Error GoTo 0
Next


End Sub
```

Comment: Please see my recent message to @A.S.H. and would appreciate your feedback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code seems ok (I tried it quickly), except one error:

```
Cells(i, 9).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction(GeneCheck, vArr, 2, False)
```

You forgot to insert VLookup. But you dont need to redo again this lookup anyway, you already did it and have the value in x. So:

```
Cells(i, 9).Value = x
```

Comment: please recheck arrays declaration and program run through stages as mentioned by you that code seems ok. I tried to run the program but it seems not to print the values into column 9. May be OP has done some more changes, if so let the program be updated.

Comment: @skkakkar I did check the code, as I said for some values in the array, and it works after making the suggested modification, printing the second value of the array in column I. I cannot figure out why it does not work with you. did you. Maybe you forgot to split the  key in two parts, putting the part until _QC in column A and the rest in column F.

Comment: Thanks I will retry it.

Comment: I have solved my problem taking reference of your feedback and referring to this link: <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31386519/vba-output-2d-an-array-to-sheet-issue/31386915#31386915> Thanks.

Comment: A.S.H suggestions worked for me.  Thank you all for taking your time to reseach this!

Comment: lol..that is a link to my old post...you would think I would figure out how to work with arrays by now...A.S.H suggestions worked for me.  The code is working as intended...Thank you all for taking your time to reseach this! I'm really grateful!